# Skipped condition and I don't know why

Tags: c++, debugging

I was debugging this, and debugger skipped the last 'if' even 'sum' was equal to 'n' and jump straight to 'else', I don't know why. Please help.

P/s: Can I use dynamic array to increase the mobility of my program?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

int exponent_of_10();                // set position for digits
int exponent_of_10(int a, int b){
for(int j = b; j>0;j--)
{
    a *= 10;
}
return a;
}

main() //check if the number was palindromic 
{
int n;  
int a[6]={0,0,0,0,0,0}; 
int i = 0;

int temp;
int S;

cout<< "Input n (maximum of 6 digits): ";
cin>> n;
do
{
    if(n<1)
    {break;}

    temp=n%10;
    a[i]=temp;
    n=(n-temp)/10;
    i++;
}
while (n!=0);

int sum = 0;
for(int j=0; j<=5; j++)
{
    exponent_of_10(a[j],j);
    S = exponent_of_10(a[j],j);
    if (S==0)
    {break;}
    sum +=S;
}

if(sum==n)
{
    cout<< "Congratz, this is PALIDROMIC NUMBER !!";
}
else
cout<< "Sad life, this is NOT palidromic number";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: @EdChum - its a `do ... while` loop, not a `while` loop

Comment: @EdChum Isn't that required for a `do {} while();` loop?

Comment: If it went straight to `else` - the condition in the `if` clause was `false`. Use debugger to figure out why.

Comment: Sorry it looked funny to me instantly for a moment

Comment: Are you *sure* it skipped? What was the value of `sum` and `n`? Is the code you show the actual code you debugged?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg thank you so much for your complaint, now I've just realized that value of 'n' was set to 0 after the loop as I add 'n' to watch

Answer (score 1):

When the code exits the `do ... while()` loop, `n` is 0. For the test in the `if` to be meaningful, the code should save the original value of `n` somewhere and compare `sum` to that original value.